# Computational complexity logic

Tags: logic, computational-complexity

Intuitionistic logic only proves theorems for which there exists a corresponding algorithm. Is there a logic which only proves theorems for which there exists a polynomial-time algorithm?

Comment: There are polytime complete grammars.  That is, every algorithm in the grammar is polytime and every function with a polytime algorithm can be implemented in the grammar.

Comment: There are variants of Girard's linear logic whose proofs correspond to polynomial-time algorithms. I've seen things of this sort with names like "bounded linear logic" and "light linear logic" but I don't know enough about these things to give you useful information. Try googling "linear logic" and "polynomial time" (together).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but [Horn-satisfiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability) for propositional clauses is [P-Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete). That is, any problem in P can be reduced to propositional Horn satisfiability. Have a look at the other P-Complete problems in the Wikipedia article cited above to see if they're closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: How complex are the reductions? Log-space?

Comment: @AndreasBlass: ["The specific type of reduction used varies and may affect the exact set of problems"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete). The article then goes on to discuss options like NC and log-space.